# Need an asp.net control to click the button in another asp.net control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

First time I have used the site. I appreciate the help I have gotten from the users before and hope to contribute as well as ask. Now, for the question.

I am developing a static toolbar that rests on the bottom on the webpage. The purpose is to display a couple of values to a user purchasing something and for the toolbar to update the information to reflect the choices. There is currently a box on the page that does this, but it rests at the top and the user would have to continuously scroll to see options appear, price changes, etc.

The values update just fine with the price in that box when certain check box buttons are clicked that auto-refresh the page (due to these check boxes changing pieces of the code). However, some things that can effect the price require a button on the page that 'recalculates' to be clicked. The information on this page is put on the page with a controller. The toolbar I am creating is a separate control.

What I am trying to do is have a button within the toolbar that will mimic the actions of the purchase button that recalculates. I tried doing this:

```
  Code on control page for toolbar: 
<input type="button" id="buttonID" class="buttonClass" runat="server"   onclick="__doPostBack('<%= btnIDOtherControl.ClientID %>','OnClick');" value="Recalculate" />

Code on control with the purchase info:
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnIdOtherControl" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image.jpg"
                                AlternateText="Recalculate" OnClick="recalcFunction_Click" />
```

That is just the current iteration. Before I did not have the 'OnClick' piece of the __doPostBack, I had ''. I also tried using a bit of jQuery. There are quite a few questions about firing an ASP.net button from javascript, but none seemed to work.

What happens is I have gotten it to a point where clicking the recalculate button in the toolbar actually DOES refresh the page, but none of the values change. If I click the recalculate button from the purchase page (where it exists normally), the value in the toolbar does not change even though the values on the page do. If I hit the recalculate button from the toolbar AFTER recalculating from the main page, the toolbar values reflect the regular values. Any other normal use of the page (such as the checkbox that auto-refreshes) will change the values correctly in both places.

If more info is needed just let me know.

Appreciate the help ahead of time!

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't use controls.  Also, you might have better luck getting answers if you actually narrow the scope of this question to a specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On you other control make a public property with set only and call your button's click event in it, Then on your working control you have to call only that public property of other control. it should be like this :

```
public void PublicPropertyCallingEvent
{
    set
    {
        Button1_ClickEvent(null,null);
    }
}
```

You have to access this property only wherever you need.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done by using javascript or jQuery.

Use the code below:

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
   $("#btnIdOtherControl").click();
});
```

This will trigger the button on other control to be triggered.

PS: Make sure that the ids are correct once the page is rendered in html as visual studio will append the ids of the button in the control to be (id of the control)_(actual id of the button) i.e. If on your page you have referenced control as

```
<user:control id="control" runat="server">
```

The id of your button (buttonID) on html will be control_buttonID, so you will need to use that (control_buttonID) in jQuery.

So your code will be

```
$("#control_buttonID").click(function(){
   $("#control1_btnIdOtherControl").click();
});
```